# How to measure XAML/UI performance in Universal Windows App?

Tags: c#, xaml, user-interface, win-universal-app, uwp

I'm building a Universal Windows App (UWP) using the "Blank App" Visual C# template in Visual Studio.  I want to measure two data points when I run my app:

- How long does it take for the UI to fully update after a XAML element is created/changed?
- How long does the program take to process the XAML elements internally, regardless of whether or not the changes are reflected in the UI yet?

**For the first point**, let's say I'm creating an app that has 5 ToggleSwitches defined as XAML in MainPage.xaml.  I want to measure how long it takes for the UI to show all 5 ToggleSwitches.  I've placed a Stopwatch timer right before the this.InitializeComponent() command in MainPage.xaml.cs (as I assume this is where the processing of Designer XAML elements begins).  I want to stop the timer as soon as the window is properly painted.  I've experimented with the Loaded and LayoutUpdated events for a XAML element, but neither is triggered as the UI is updated.  Where do I place my timer to get the data I seek?  If I'm stepping through code in the debugger, at what line of code would "Step Over" cause the UI to refresh?

**For the second point**, I just want to record how long the computer takes to internally process the XAML code (not including rendering the UI, running the composition engine, processing with Direct3D - just processing the XAML). My first instinct was to simply start the Stopwatch before this.InitializeComponent() and end immediately afterwards.  However, I'm not seeing a change in data based on the content of the page.  For example, whether I run my app with 100 ToggleSwitches or 5 ToggleSwitches defined on the XAML Designer, the this.InitializeComponent() method takes the same amount of time.  Any ideas how I can better measure this data point?

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: This may help: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa969767(v=vs.110).aspx I'm not sure how MS does the performance analysis but I'm guessing it uses low level hooks. There is a lot of WPF that is offloaded to things like the GPU that make it difficult to measure with a stopwatch and events.

Answer (score 3):

Application Timeline tool could probably help you (available with Visual Studio 2015).

[image: Timeline]
<sub>(source: [s-msft.com](https://i-msdn.sec.s-msft.com/dynimg/IC790153.jpeg))</sub>

Analyze UI responsiveness with the Application Timeline tool
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn957934.aspx

Comment: Great tool, thanks for the answer.  For the question I asked, this is actually pretty spot on.  Just to add some info - it appears that Application Timeline doesn't work for certain Remote Machines, which happens to be the case for my project!